# How do I create a list of data based on actual twig files within project

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I am creating an app via NPM using https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-twig-render. It essentially is twig.js. I'm keeping it slim, so right now there isn't any other php or anything like that. Just npm / twig.js and other npm packages, including Grunt.

Here's what I'm trying to do. Right now, I have a bunch of twig files within subfolders of a directory.

What I'd like to do is generate a list of data of the .twig files in that subdirectory. Something like this may work well

```
files: [
{
"name": "file1.twig"
"path": "/folder1"
},
{
"name": "file2.twig"
"path": "/folder1"
},
{
"name": "file3.twig"
"path": "/folder1"
}
]
```

But I'm not super picky. Just seeing if anyone has found a way to create a list of files within a folder via npm, or twigjs, or something similar.

If it generates a .json file, that would be ideal. This would be part of a build process, so doing that via Grunt would work well too.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a [custom grunt task](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks) in your `Gruntfile.js` which utilizes the `shelljs` [find](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#findpath--path-) method to retrieve the path of each `.twig` file.

[shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) is a package which provides portable Unix shell commands for Node.js. It's `find` method is analogous to the Bash [find](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) command.

The following steps describe how to achieve your requriement:

1. `cd` to your project directory and install `shelljs` by running:

   ```
   npm i -D shelljs
   ```
2. Configure your `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

   **Gruntfile.js**

   ```js
   module.exports = function(grunt) {

     // requirements
     var path = require('path'),
       find = require('shelljs').find;

     grunt.initConfig({
       // other tasks ...
     });

     /**
      * Custom grunt task generates a list of .twig files in a directory
      * and saves the results as .json file.
      */
     grunt.registerTask('twigList', 'Creates list of twig files', function() {
       var obj = {};

       obj.files = find('path/to/directory')
           .filter(function(filePath) {
             return filePath.match(/\.twig$/);
           })
           .map(function(filePath) {
             return {
               name: path.basename(filePath),
               path: path.dirname(filePath)
             }
           });

       grunt.file.write('twig-list.json', JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
     });

     grunt.registerTask('default', ['twigList']);
   };
   ```

#### Explanation

1. Both `shelljs` and nodes built-in [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module are `require`d into `Gruntfile.js`.
2. Next a custom task named `twigList` is registered.

   - In the body of the function we initialize an empty object and assign it to a variable named `obj`.
   - Next, the shelljs `find` method is invoked passing in a path to the subdirectory containing the `.twig` files. Currently the path is set to `path/to/directory` so you'll need to redefine this path as necessary.

     **Note:** The `find` method can also accept an array of multiple directory paths as an argument. For example:

     ```js
     find(['path/to/directory', 'path/to/another/directory'])
     ```
   - The `find` method returns an Array of all paths found inside the given directory, (many levels deep). We utilize the Array's [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to `return` only filepaths with a `.twig` file extension by providing a regex (`\.twig$`) to the Strings [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method.
   - Each item of the resultant Array of `.twig` filepaths is passed to the Array's [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. It `return`s an Object with two properties (`name` and `path`). The value for the `name` property is obtained from the full filepath using nodes [`path.basename()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) method. Similarly, the value for the `path` property is obtained from the full filepath using nodes [`path.dirname()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_path) method.
   - Finally the grunt [`file.write()`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.write) method is utilized to write a `.json` file to disk. Currently the first argument is set to `twig-list.json`. This will result in a file named `twig-list.json` being saved to the top-level of your project directory where `Gruntfile.js` resides. You'll need to redefine this output path as necessary. The second argument is provided by utilizing [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert `obj` to JSON. The resultant JSON is indented by two spaces.

#### Additional info

As previously mentioned the *shelljs* `find` method lists all files (many levels deeep) in the given directory path. If the directory path provided includes a subfolder(s) containing `.twig` files that you want to *exclude* you can do something like the following in the `filter()` method:

```js
.filter(function(file) {
    return filePath.match(/\.twig$/) && !filePath.match(/^foo\/bar/);
})
```

This will match all `.twig` files, and ignore those in the sub directory `foo/bar` of the given directory, e.g. `path/to/directory`.