# Using Twig or Grunt to create navigation from JSON array

Tags: json, npm, gruntjs, twig

I got some help [generating JSON from folder structure via Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661546/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-data-based-on-actual-twig-files-within-project). That worked great.

Now, I want to take that JSON and create a menu based on the output.

Here is a sample of what I'm talking about.

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "firstpage.twig",
      "path": "folder1/subfolder1"
    },
    {
      "name": "secondpage.twig",
      "path": "folder1/subfolder1"
    },
    {
      "name": "thirdpage.twig",
      "path": "folder1/subfolder1"
    },
    {
      "name": "fourthpage.twig",
      "path": "folder1/subfolder1"
    },
    {
      "name": "anotherpage.twig",
      "path": "folder1/subfolder2"
    },
    {
      "name": "yetanother.twig",
      "path": "folder1/subfolder2"
    },
    {
      "name": "heresanother.twig",
      "path": "folder2/subfolder3"
    },
    {
      "name": "anotherone.twig",
      "path": "folder2/subfolder3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to build a nav so that it would be like

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">folder1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#!">subfolder1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="folder1/subfolder1/firstpage.twig">firstpage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="folder1/subfolder1/secondpage.twig">secondpage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="folder1/subfolder1/thirdpage.twig">thirdpage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="folder1/subfolder1/fourthpage.twig">fourthpage</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#!">subfolder2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="folder1/subfolder2/anotherpage.twig">anotherpage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="folder1/subfolder2/yetanother.twig">yetanother</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#!">folder2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#!">subfolder3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="folder1/subfolder1/heresanother.twig">heresanother</a></li>
                    <li><a href="folder1/subfolder1/anotherone.twig">anotherone</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The sections of folder1, subfolder1, etc would be dynamically populated based off of going through the path entries within the JSON and parsing the unique ones out.

I am using a Grunt custom task to generate the JSON. I also am using Twig that gets rendered via a [Twig Rendering Grunt package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-twig-render). There is no other framework to play with here, just pure Twig. It's all done through NPM.

I tried this so far but am obviously failing

```
{% for folder in files %}
    {% set folders = folder.path|split('/') %}
    {% for i in folders if i (doesn't already exist) %}
        // Dynamic menu goes here
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Just stuck here banging my head off the desk. :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In the Gruntfile, the custom task that works is like this:

grunt.registerTask('twigList', 'Creates list of twig files', function() {
       var obj = {};

```
   obj.files = find('sections')
       .filter(function(filePath) {
         return filePath.match(/\.twig$/);
       })
       .map(function(filePath) {
         let itemPath = path.dirname(filePath).replace('sections/','');
         let pathSeparatorPos = itemPath.indexOf('/');
         let rootPath = itemPath.substring(0, pathSeparatorPos);

         return {
           name: path.basename(filePath),
           path: itemPath,
           rootPath: rootPath,
         }
       });

   grunt.file.write('data/page-list.json', JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
 });
```

and then the quick and dirty twig is this

```
{% set _lastRootPath = false %}
    {% for folder in files if folder.rootPath is not empty %}
    {% if folder.rootPath != _lastRootPath %}
    {% set _lastRootPath = folder.rootPath %}
    <a href="">{{ folder.rootPath }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% set _lastRootPath = false %}
    <ul>
    {% for folder in files if folder.rootPath is not empty %}
    {% if folder.rootPath != _lastRootPath %}
        {% if _lastRootPath != false %}</ul></li>{% endif %}
    {% set _lastRootPath = folder.rootPath %}
    <li><a href="">{{ folder.rootPath }}</a><ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% if folder.rootPath == _lastRootPath %}
    <li><a href="">{{ folder.name }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It's not polished but it works